# Ni-Fi Get request with headers using InvokeHTTP

Tags: http, header, apache-nifi

I am trying to send a Get request with the following header:

```
Cookie: uac.csrftoken=VwJryg1rJBC3sddwHarr497lKgQgMq; 
        expires=Mon, 15-Nov-2021 12:12:24 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; 
        uac.authorization=2dA2631879fc4dc2e9;
```

in NiFi I have sent a request to get the requiered parameters and assigned it to the flow file attributes :
[image]

[image]

Now I need to combine both to have the same format as the Header above,

what do I need to add to the field attributes to send to do that?
[image]

I tried multiple ways and nothing worked, it says here
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, This can be done by adding any custom Dynamic Property in the InvokeHTTPProcessor. Example in my case :
[image]